# Can we say that, every algebraic curve is a piecewise ${C^\infty }$ curve?

Tags: algebraic-curves

Let $L$ be algebraic curve.

Can we say that, $L$ is a piecewise ${C^\infty }$ curve?

Answer (score 2):

You're thinking of an algebraic curve over the reals?

Then yes, because the singular locus is a subvariety and therefore consists of finitely many points.

Comment: I need a good reference for 'properties of algebraic curve'. Please guide me.

Comment: Well, if you want to know much more than the basics you'd have to learn some algebraic geometry.  William Fulton's book on Algebraic Curves is available from his website if you're interested.